# Error when use akka http unmarshall entity as case class with default value

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Error found when I send a http post request:

> The request content was malformed: No usable value for gender Did
>   not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String

My request body:

```
{
    "name":"test"
}
```

Route in my scala code:

```
path("test"){
        (post(entity(as[People]) { req =>
          val resp = queryData(req)
          complete(resp.meta.getOrElse("statusCode", 200).asInstanceOf[Int] -> resp)
        }))
    } ~
```

Code for `People`:

```
case class People(name: String, gender: String = "male")
```

Why still get the `malformed` error ???

Comment: I am using `akka-http 10.1.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you put a default value, the extraction of the Json will look for that field, and it is not present there, so it will fail.
(I am assuming you are using spray-json as it's the default one in akka-http)

In order to avoid the issue, while keeping it simple, I would recommend you to create a case class for the request to create people, which contains an Option[String] for that field, and you can then convert the PeopleCreateRequest to a People easily.

```
case class PeopleCreateRequest(name: String, gender: Option[String])
```

That will work nicely with the framework...

Alternatively, if you want to keep the design that way, you'll need to look into implementing your own JsonFormat[People] which will treat this value as optional but add a default value when missing.

Look into spray-json https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types

But I imagine it would be something like:

```
implicit val peopleFormat = new RootJsonFormat[People] {
    def read(json: JsValue): People = json match {
      case JsArray(Seq(JsString(name), JsString(gender))) =>
        People(name, gender)
      case JsArray(Seq(JsString(name))) =>
        People(name)
      case _ => deserializationError("Missing fields")
    }

    def write(obj: People): JsValue = ???
  }
```

I am normally using different JsonSupport, using circe, but hopefully this gives you direction to solve your issue